# nested sysfunc + cat + leading 0 removed

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm trying with the below loop to manage a dynamic append between three tables.

However, the nested cat with %sysfuncs removed the zeros from the month and the day

Would be someone so gentle to explain what Is not working fine here?

I'm expecting to dynamically declares the table like, ex.

"FTP.TOTAL_4B_20170603" (yyyymmdd) and not like the code is retriving: "FTP.TOTAL_4B_201763"

```
    data dd; %MACRO H;
%DO I=1 %TO 2;
proc append 
base=prod0 
data=FTP.TOTAL_4B_%sysfunc(CATS(%sysfunc(year(%sysfunc(intnx(day,%sysfunc(today()),-&i,s)))),
%sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(month(%sysfunc(intnx(day,%sysfunc(today()),-&i,s)))),z2.)),
%sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(day(%sysfunc(intnx(day,%sysfunc(today()),-&i,s)))),z2.))));
run;
%end;
proc sort data=prod0;
by pan fecha;
run;
%MEND H;
%H;
run;
```

Thanks for your help
Bests
D

Comment: Yes, the CAT_ family of functions does strip the leading 0, this is as designed, since it does automatic conversion using the BEST format. To override the default behavior you have to explicitly define the values. Others have suggest the workarounds below, but I wanted to explicitly answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you have `proc append` and `proc sort` *within* a `data` step, but I think the macro expression below could help:

```
%MACRO J;
    %DO I=1 %TO 2;
        %put FTP.TOTAL_4B_%sysfunc(intnx(DAY,%sysfunc(today()),-&I.,S),yymmddn8.);
    %END;   
%MEND J;
%J;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use formats, to get the date YYYYMMDD. Also intnx is not necessary if you are going to iterate on days only. date() returns integer, so you can easily use addition/subtraction.

```
%MACRO test;
    %DO I=1 %TO 2;
        %let test_date=%sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(date()) - &i, yymmddn8.));
        %put DS name FTP.TOTAL_4B_&test_date;
    %end;
%MEND test;

%test;
```

Gives the result

```
 1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 59         
 60         
 61         
 62         
 63         %MACRO test;
 64         %DO I=1 %TO 2;
 65         %let test_date=%sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(date())-&i, yymmddn8.));
 66         %put DS name FTP.TOTAL_4B_&test_date;
 67         %end;
 68         %MEND test;
 69         
 70         %test;
 DS name FTP.TOTAL_4B_20170612
 DS name FTP.TOTAL_4B_20170611
 71         
 72         OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 84
```